# flushright of text within align environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

```
\begin{align}
\label{eq:3.1}u &= \frac{\partial r(x,t)}{\partial t} \qquad \text{(flow velocity)}
\end{align}
```

yields the following:

[image]

I desire the text "flow velocity" to be flushed to the right and attempted to do so with `\tag{\text{flow velocity}}`, but this took the place of my label which is undesired. How do I flush the text as described?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to make the description to be zero width (or some eye-computed width in case there's overlap)

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% for mock text
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}% to see the margins

\newcommand{\eqname}[2][0pt]{\makebox[#1][r]{(#2)}}

\begin{document}

\kant*[1][1-6]
\begin{flalign}
&& u &= \frac{\partial r(x,t)}{\partial t} & \eqname{flow velocity} \\
&& v &= a+b & \eqname{something else}
\end{flalign}
Just to check centering
\[u = \frac{\partial r(x,t)}{\partial t}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the optional argument (a length), the equation would be pushed left: use it when the equation or the description is too long and forcing the equation to be centered would not be appropriate.

```
\begin{flalign}
&& u &= \frac{\partial r(x,t)}{\partial t} & \eqname[6em]{flow velocity} \\
&& v &= a+b & \eqname[6em]{something else}
\end{flalign}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `flalign` environment, which takes up the full horizontal width, although in order to keep the main aligned equation group near the center, rather than the left, you could put in a blank equation set to its left with `& &` before the start of the equation set in the middle:

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]% dummy text so you can see where the margin is

\begin{flalign}
\label{eq:3.1} & & u &= \frac{\partial r(x,t)}{\partial t} & \text{(flow velocity)}
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

[image: flalign example]

Answer (score 3):

Here's another `flalign`-based solution, which places the equation close to the middle of the horizontal line (as opposed to, say, equidistant from the material at the left- and right-hand edges).

[image]

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\counterwithin{equation}{section} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{3} % just for this example

\begin{flalign}\label{eq:3.1}
&&&&  u = \frac{\partial r(x,t)}{\partial t} && \text{(flow velocity)}
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```